# 7z all files in directory, remove originals

Tags: linux, compression

I have some directories (linux machine) full of highly compressible *.foo files.

Right now I just have a script that does `gzip *.foo` and it gzips each file into its own .gz file, and removes the original. 7z will compress these files to half the size that gzip will, so I'd like to switch to that.

How can I use 7z to start with a directory like this

```
file1.foo
file2.foo
file3.foo
```

and end up with

```
file1.foo.7z
file2.foo.7z
file3.foo.7z
```

Or similar. I don't want all of the files in one .7z archive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in *.foo; do 7za a $i.7z $i; if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then rm $i; fi; done
```

Comment: Simplified: `for i in *.foo; do 7za a $i.7z $i && rm $i; done`

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
find -type f -maxdepth 1 -name "*.foo" -print0 | xargs -0 -I % 7z a %.7z %
```

but that will leave the original file after it's compressed.